# I cannot connect to Gcloud instance using ssh, since cpu is 99.9% of use

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a gcloud vm instance of type custom (4 vCPUs, 8 GB memory), with ubuntu 16.04, 10Gb disk space. Today at specific time (7:30 am), start using the 99% of cpu. I restart the machine but continue to use the 99% of cpu. Now I cannot connect through ssh. There is any workaround to connect to my instance and see what the problem is?? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to the instance [through serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) if you want an interactive shell. The command is `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME]`.

The [viewing-serial-port-output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) for GCE instances also might be helpful in quickly glancing through serial port logs.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That works great!! I was able to clear the hdd. That was the problem, hdd out of space